# Expression must be pointer to complete object type?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to make changes to an array of structures.  My code is as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    char firstName[30];
    char lastName[30];
    char street[35];
    char city[20];
    char state[3];
    int zip;
    char phone[15];
    int accountId;
} Customer;

struct Customer customer_list[];

//void copy_first_name(char data[], int i) {
//  strcpy(customer_list[i].)

//}

int main(void) {

    int _zip, _accountId;
    char _firstName[30], _lastName[30], _street[35], _city[20], _state[3], _phone[15];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        printf("Enter data for customer %d: \n", i);
        printf("Enter First Last Phone: ");
        scanf("%s%s%s", &_firstName, &_lastName, &_phone);

        printf("\nEnter Address (Street City State ZIP): ");
        scanf("%s%s%s%d", &_street, &_city, &_state, &_zip);

        strcpy(customer_list[i].firstName, _firstName);


    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the error message in the title, referring to customer_list.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Your `customer_list` array has no size.  Try defining it with 10 elements.

Comment: Definitely a good idea! Still not sure about the main issue though...

Comment: I just made that change actually, and it had no effect with regards to the issue described in my post.

Comment: You don't have type `struct Customer` since you've used `typedef`, only `Customer`.

Comment: Side note: you should not reference the `char` arrays when using `scanf`.  Take out those ampersands (`&`) and allow the compiler to convert the array to a pointer.

Comment: Interesting.  What would be the proper way to define it?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
struct Customer customer_list[];
```

to

```
Customer customer_list[10];
```

or (not recommended, but an example of the syntax)

```
struct Customer {
    char firstName[30];
    char lastName[30];
    char street[35];
    char city[20];
    char state[3];
    int zip;
    char phone[15];
    int accountId;
} customer_list[];
```

In your example, `Customer` is a typedef, equal to `struct { ... }`. It is not a named struct.

Some people like to do this, but I don't like it:

```
typedef struct Customer {
    char firstName[30];
    char lastName[30];
    char street[35];
    char city[20];
    char state[3];
    int zip;
    char phone[15];
    int accountId;
} Customer;

Customer customer_list[10];
```

or

```
struct Customer customer_list[10];
```

It would be better if they did:

```
typedef struct Customer_s {
    char firstName[30];
    char lastName[30];
    char street[35];
    char city[20];
    char state[3];
    int zip;
    char phone[15];
    int accountId;
} Customer;
```

Now it is clear that there is a difference between `Customer` and `Customer_s`.

```
Customer customer_list[10];
```

or

```
struct Customer_s customer_list[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `[typedef][1]` in `struct` so while declaring no need of `struct` keyword
do simply

```
Customer customer_list[10];
```

is enough.

or remove the `typedef` and declare `struct` like this ..

```
struct Customer {
    char firstName[30];
    char lastName[30];
    char street[35];
    char city[20];
    char state[3];
    int zip;
    char phone[15];
    int accountId;
} ;

struct Customer customer_list[10];
```